# send result from HTTP GET request with a telegram bot

Tags: node.js, openshift, telegram-bot, unirest

**EDIT**: testing only the code for the GET-Request (without telegram api) on my raspberry pi. Instead of sending a tg message, I write it to a file. I've discovered that the magic happens in this part:

```
req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
  });
```

The `console.log(res.body)`gives me this output (which are the correct names of tables / columns):

```
{ test: 
   { columns: [ 'eventID', 'event_desc' ],
     records: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] } }
```

But if I replace it with `fs.appendFile("getrequest.log",res.body + "\n");` I only get:

```
[object Object]
```

**Any idea why the result changes when I use another function?**

---

Original question:

I'm really new in to nodejs and the telegram bot api.

What I'm trying is to make a HTTP GET request to an URL, which returns data in JSON format. I'd like that the bot is sending that result into the chat.

My bot is running on openshift and is written in NodeJS, using [this guide and code sample](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api). To figure out the code for the GET request, i've used [postman](https://www.getpostman.com). It already helped me to make a POST request to this URL. So I'm using unirest and this code:

```
bot.onText(/\/list (.+)/, function (msg, match) {

  var fromId = msg.chat.id;
  var eventDb = match[1];
  var eventURL = "https://api.italianrockmafia.ch/api.php/";
  eventURL += eventDb;
  var unirest = require("unirest");

  var req = unirest("GET", eventURL);

  req.headers({
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  });

  req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
  });
  bot.sendMessage(fromId, req);
});
```

So I'm not sure which value i must use in `bot.sendMessage();` and where I must use this function. I've tried several combinations ( with `req`,`res`,`res.body`) But none of them worked.

If I use the code just like above, the log says `message ist empty`. 
When I change the last lines to:

```
req.end(function (res) {
    bot.sendMessage(fromId, res);
   if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

   console.log(res.body);
 });
```

the log only throws up a "Wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified" in a file of the telegram module it self. This message shows up at every command (even that ones which are working).

So my 2 questions are:

- **Which value do I need to send?**
- **Where in the code do I need to put `bot.sendMessage` in?**

I'm struggling really at those two, so some help is really appreciated!

Comment: Seeing the same thing with I bot I developed today. This looks related: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/pull/435

Comment: At a HTTP GET request? I have this error at every command in my bot, but they still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had no clue how to handle JSON. layer 8 error...

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the [inputfile](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile) limitations

> Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram
>   will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB
>   max for other types of content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure if I unterstand it right, but in my example I don't try to send I file. I want to send the body of the page I sent the HTTP request to. (REST API). Also. postman says the answer is only 976 Bytes big...